# HTML Drop Down Menu navigation doesn't show up

Tags: html, css, user-interface, drop-down-menu

I am trying to learn HTML/CSS and during the course I thought of creating a CSS based Drop Down Menu Navigation bar. I read almost all of the tutorials I could find and finally built it, but the problem is it doesn't work as expected, I got the Main menu working but, the lists are not showing up. Here's the structure of my HTML:

```
 <div id="Header"/>
 <div id="Navigation" > 
<ul id="Menu-H">

        <li id="HOME"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>

        <li id="ITEMS"><a href="#">ITEMS</a></li>
    <ul >
        <li><a href="#">New Item</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Search Item</a></li>
    </ul>

        <li id="Category"><a href="#">CATALOG</a></li>

        <li id="Inventory"><a href="#">INVENTORY</a></li>

    </ul>
<a class="LogOutButton" href="#">LOG OUT</a>
```

And here is the CSS I built:

```
#Menu-H {    
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    list-style-type: none; 
    margin-left: 50px;      
}

#Menu-H  li {    
    float:left;
}

#Menu-H li:hover {    
    background: #f4f4f4;
    border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
}

#Menu-H  li  a {

    //border-left: 2px solid blue;
    //border-right: 2px solid blue;
    //background-color: white;
    display:block;
    padding: 5px 15px 5px 15px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #FFFFFF
}

#Menu-H li:hover a {    
    color: #161616;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px#FFFFFF;
}


/* Drop Down Menu.........*/

#Menu-H ul {    
    background: #161616;
    background:rgba(255,255,255,0);
    list-style: none;
    display: none;
}

Menu-H ul li {    
    padding-top: 1px;;
    float: none;    
}

Menu-H li:hover ul {    
    display:block;
}

#Menu-H li:hover a {    
    background: #6b0c36;        
}

#Menu-H li:hover ul li a:hover {    
    background: #333;
}
```

I can not find the reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is't right, You need to place the secondary `<ul>` inside the parent `<li>`

```
<ul id="Menu-H">

        <li id="HOME"><a href="#">HOME</a></li>
        <li id="ITEMS"><a href="#">ITEMS</a>
           <ul>
              <li><a href="#">New Item</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Search Item</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>   

        <li id="Category"><a href="#">CATALOG</a></li>
        <li id="Inventory"><a href="#">INVENTORY</a></li>

</ul>
```

Also you forgot to add the `#` in the CSS for two id-s. Here's a fiddle I made where you can see I made some changes that I was talking about and it works:

http://jsfiddle.net/SJQ9B/